# mysql_real_escape_string removing linefeeds from stored email

Tags: php, mysql, imap, sql-injection

I collect emails from my mailserver with imap_mail (php), explode the result and save it to database after using mysql_real_escape_string.

If I display it in a textarea after retrieving from db, all linefeeds are gone or replaced by \r etc.

without mysql_real_escape_string  they are displayed.

How do I get them back if I escape?
Or rather, as I do not have access to that part of the php code that display in the text area: how do I protect the strings from sql injection so that linefeeds are still shown?

many thanks,

Klaus

Comment: when you take it out of the database, it should display fine and in the format you put it in there... you don't need to undo `mysql_real_escape_string` when you pull the data out later.

Comment: There is something else going on, mysql_real_escape_string will not do what you are saying.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated, it would be in your best interest to make new coding use the `mysqli_*` functions. `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, data);`

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get them back if I escape?

this function never interfere with linefeeds, if used properly. so, it's some other code that interfere.

> how do I protect the strings from sql injection

[Use prepared statements.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

And get rid of whatever code that spoils your linefeeds.